# Changing axis min/max on an existing plot using Flot JQuery Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, zooming, flot

I've created a series of plots using the flot library, which are all displayed on a single page. Is there a way to update the X axis min and max options (options.xaxis.min, options.axis.max) values WITHOUT re-plotting the plots ($.plot('placeholder',data,options))?

I found this solution: http://osdir.com/ml/flot-graphs/2012-02/msg00064.html
Which suggests that the following line would do it, but it does not work for me - the plots visible min and max are not modified based on this call.

```
monitorGraph.getOptions().xaxis[0].max = xaxis.max;
```

Any tips on updating the graphs xaxis max and min values would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: Solution Below**

The following code will take an existing plot, update the range that is visible, and redraw it in a very light and efficient way.

```
            plot.getOptions().xaxis[0].min = time.start;
            plot.getOptions().xaxis[0].max = time.end;
            plot.setupGrid();
            plot.draw();
```

Comment: To specify futher: I would like the plots to reflect the new x min and max, but I would not like to re-plot them completely, since that is very expensive and seems to be slowing down the process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After you set the value of the yaxis max height, try

```
yourPlot.setupGrid();
```

Not sure if it'll be as smooth as you want but I think it does the trick.

Comment: This helped a lot! Major improvement over calling .plot each time. Thank you!

Comment: Oops, at second glance it seems 
    myPlot.setupGrid();
also does not update the plot visually in any way. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm I went on flot's website and just dicked around in the console. Maybe try setupGride then also try draw()?

Comment: and are you sure that you did "monitorGraph.getOptions().yaxes[0].max = whateverheightyouwant" before you did setupGrid()?

Comment: I tried both in a row and they seem to not effect the plots - although that is what the flot website says they are supposed to do. There may be an issue with how I am storing my plots. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah make sure the variable you are using in place of "myPlot" is actually a reference to your plot. And if it works out, accept my answer! Cheers

Answer (score 12):

You can also dynamically modify MIN/MAX parameters in axis options:

```
plot.getAxes().xaxis.options.min = 0;
plot.getAxes().xaxis.options.max = 999; 

plot.setupGrid();
plot.draw();
```